# HAProxy Front End

Tags: haproxy

I've got a very tech-savvy client who want me to set up a haproxy instance for them.

I have no troubles doing this, and adding the initial config, however they're quite good technically and enjoy the ability to change basic config settings on their own (for adding new websites, domains, changing IP addresses, etc).

haproxy is pretty easy to screw up manually editing config files (isn't everything? Everything they change at the moment is Windows-based, so not so easy to screw up), so I'm wondering if anyone knows of any haproxy front-ends?

I've found a product [Snapt-UI](http://www.snapt-ui.com/products/snaptha/) that looks very promising, and I have absolutally no problem forking out $US200 for it, but I want to see if there are any other offerings before comitting.

Comment: Snapt-UI is the only one I'm aware of.

Comment: "very tech-savvy" and "all Windows-based" is somewhat of an Oxymoron I always thought :)

Comment: @syneticon - that's not constructive at all. I'm not interested in Windows bashing.

Comment: Comments are not necessarily meant to be constructive. But to contribute something of relevance to this discussion, I'd like refer to [a statement I fully agree with](http://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg01679.html). As a bonus, it has two references to commercial products using haproxy and coming with a configuration frontend.

Comment: @synet - normally comments somehow contribute to the question. Yours did not, and I'm sick and tired of the attitude a lot of people still seem to have about Windows vs *nix (for the record, we're 90% windows, 10% *nix, like most SMBs). Your comment also had nothing to do with your link. However, your link is useful, and I tend to agree with what it says, but I'll do whatever my clients are paying me for. Feel free to post it as an answer quoting what's inside the link.

Comment: My first comment was just a different way of telling you that a GUI "not easy to screw up" will not be able to map the technical complexity that comes with the configuration of haproxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not be suitable for your needs. But template configuration like this is much better managed through something like [puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) of [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/). A side effect of this is that you end up finding it more difficult to screw up the configuration files.